# What is the meaning of this error "Invalid KeySchema: Some index key attribute have no definition (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2);

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework

Could you please tell me anything that I've missed at this code.

```
resources:
  Resources:
    ScholarshipsTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        TableName: purrfectScholarshipsTable
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: postId
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: postId
            KeyType: HASH
        GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
          - IndexName: scholarshipCategoryIndex
            KeySchema:
              - AttributeName: category
                KeyType: HASH
              - AttributeName: deadline
                KeyType: RANGE
            Projection:
              ProjectionType: "ALL"
        BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
```

I use the serverless framework and I got the error. Any mistakes that I make?

Answer (score 3):

Every key you use in any index (GSI, LSI, etc) needs to be listed in the `AttributeDefinitions` block. So this should work:

```
resources:
  Resources:
    ScholarshipsTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        TableName: purrfectScholarshipsTable
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: postId
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: category
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: deadline
            AttributeType: N
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: postId
            KeyType: HASH
        GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
          - IndexName: scholarshipCategoryIndex
            KeySchema:
              - AttributeName: category
                KeyType: HASH
              - AttributeName: deadline
                KeyType: RANGE
            Projection:
              ProjectionType: "ALL"
        BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
```

You can read more in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-dynamodb-attributedef.html)